# DataContract / JsonSerializer '@' appended to variable names

Tags: c#, .net, json, f#, datacontract

For some reason when I serialize a type (f#):

```
type JsonKeyValuePair<'T, 'S> =  {
    [<DataMember>] 
    mutable key : 'T
    [<DataMember>] 
    mutable value : 'S
}

let printJson() = 

    use stream = new MemoryStream() 
    use reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)

    let o = {key = "a"; value = 1 }
    let jsonSerializer = Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<TestGrounds.JsonKeyValuePair<string, int>>)

    jsonSerializer.WriteObject (stream , o)
    stream.Seek(int64 0, SeekOrigin.Begin) |> ignore 

    printfn <| Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>(reader.ReadToEnd())
    ()
```

It generates a string:

> {"key@":"a","value@":1}

and if I attempt to deserialze it without the @ sign:

```
let deserialize() = 
    let json = "{\"key\":\"b\",\"value\":2}"
    let o  = deserializeString<TestGrounds.JsonKeyValuePair<string, int>> json
    ()
```

{"The data contract type 'TestGrounds.JsonKeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'key@, value@' were not found."}

However put the @ back in:

```
let run2 () = 
    let json = "{\"key@\":\"b\",\"value@\":2}"
    let o  = deserializeString<TestGrounds.JsonKeyValuePair<string, int>> json
    ()
```

and we are all good.  As far ask i know there is no reference to @ in the Json Spec (http://www.json.org/)...

Comment: The JSON is indeed valid, so as long as you are using this internally (e.g. not expecting JavaScript scripts to consume it -- though they still could) there is no problem with the trailing @ characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# generates fields called `key@` and `value@` to back the properties called `key` and `value`.  Try putting a `DataContract` attribute on your record type - without it the serializer will ignore the `DataMember` attributes and appears to just write out every field.